# Creating WFS server with GDAL

Tags: gdal, wfs

I am trying to create a WFS server.
My intention is to answer the GetFeature request by GDAL.
Here is the scheme I am working on:

```
MyString CreateResponse(const MyVectorDataLines & data) {
    GDALDataset * gdalDataset = gmlDriver->Create("/vsimem/wfsResponse.xml", 0, 0, 0, GDT_Unknown, GdalGmlOpts);
    OGRLayer * linesLayer = gdalDataset->CreateLayer("Lines", NULL, wkbLineString, NULL);
    FillMyVectorData(data, linesLayer);
    GDALClose(gdalDataset);
    MyString response = ReadMyResponse("/vsimem/wfsResponse.xml");
    return response;
  }
```

This generates a result that is pretty close to what I am trying to do but not exactly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ogr:FeatureCollection
 gml:id="aFeatureCollection"
 xmlns:ogr="http://ogr.maptools.org/"
 xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">
  <gml:boundedBy><gml:Envelope><gml:lowerCorner>-180 -89.1984900735225</gml:lowerCorner><gml:upperCorner>180.0 83.7956225471799</gml:upperCorner></gml:Envelope></gml:boundedBy>                                                                                                                                                                               
  <ogr:featureMember>
    <ogr:Lines gml:id="Lines.0">
      <ogr:geometryProperty><gml:LineString><gml:posList>...</gml:posList></gml:LineString></ogr:geometryProperty>
    </ogr:Lines>
  </ogr:featureMember>
</ogrFeatureCollection>
```

To have a readable result (currently by OpenLayers), I need to adapt it, e.g. I need to extend xmlns definitions by wfs, I need to change ogr:featureMember to wfs:member, I need to add information about number of returned features etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection
  xmlns="http://www.myns.com/"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd http://www.myns.com/"
  numberMatched="1"
  numberReturned="1"
 >
    <wfs:member>
        <Lines>
            <Geometry>
                <gml:LineString>
                    <gml:posList>...</gml:posList>
                </gml:LineString>
            </Geometry>
        </Lines>
    </wfs:member>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

I saw on the documentation page that some of the problems could be fixed by modifying parameters for dataset creation (GmlGdalOpts in my code). I played with them but I was not able to reach my goal.

So, my questions are:

**Is it even reachable by GML driver?**

**Is there any other driver** that would be suitable for that (of course I browsed the list of vector drivers in the documentation, but I have not found anything useful)?

Comment: Best driver than comes into my mind is GMLAS https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gmlas.html "By default, the driver will “wrap” the features inside a WFS 2.0 wfs:FeatureCollection / wfs:member element. It is also possible to ask the driver to create instead a custom wrapping .xsd file that declares the ogr_gmlas:FeatureCollection / ogr_gmlas:featureMember XML elements."

Comment: WFS driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/wfs.html has also write support. You may find some reusable code from that driver about how to create GML according to the WFS schema.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but I do not think they are correct. If I am not wrong, I need creation support, not write support. And GMLAS, and WFS do not have such support. See https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html and correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: About GMLAS, at least there is a test about writing in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_gmlas.py#L1810. When it comes to WFS, I meant to suggest that you might find some re-usable code from the source code.